# Print (po) the value of a Swift anonymous closure argument from the console in Xcode

Tags: xcode, swift, closures

I have a rather simple question I hope has a simple answer. I am using Swift's `filter` method to filter a collection of objects using the anonymous closure argument `$0`:

```
let filteredArray = myArray.filter {
    $0.name != "Bob"
}
```

I have set a breakpoint inside the filter closure and just want to inspect the value of `$0`, but when I type `po $0` on the console it gives me:

> (lldb) po $0
>
> error: :2:1: error: anonymous closure argument not contained in a closure
>
> $0
>
> ^

How can I get around this?

To be clear, the code compiles and runs, but gives me this error on the console at runtime.

Comment: I'd also like to find a way to do this, but it looks like it might currently be a limitation of lldb: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-2029

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a known issue with Xcode 8.1 GM Seed.  From the [release notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_8.1_GM_Seed/Release_Notes_for_Xcode_8.1_GM_Seed.pdf):

> Anonymous closure arguments in Swift cannot be used in LLDB expressions. For example, `po $0` is not supported.

You can use the frame variable command to print its value:

```
fr va $0
```

This issue is filed as `rdar://28611943`.

Comment: `fr va $0.id` gives _error: "id" is not a member of "(MyApp.MyClass) $0"_

Comment: I'm using XCode 9.4.1 and this seems to be fixed at least in the Variables View :D

Comment: Finally! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this in order to debug with po your contents in filtered array:

```
let filteredArray = myArray.filter {
    (anElement) in anElement.name != "Bob"
}
```

Then with your breakpoint:

```
(lldb) po anElement
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm looking for a way to do it without rewriting my code if possible.